# how to Redis Cache miss for concurrent users in PHP

Tags: php, redis

### [image: PHP Redis Concurrent Connection Problem]

I am having this typical problem of multiple DB queries if the Redis key does not exist(or is expired) in case of concurrent requests for the same resource.
Please refer to the diagram.

I think if there is one request requesting a particular resource then the other(for that particular resource) should wait for the first request to complete.

Can someone help me in finding the right solution to this and is there something available in PHP?

Thanks,
Ankesh S

Comment: why does `get data from redis` wait other two requests to be completed in you diagram ?

Comment: @Ersoy It is not waiting for anything, I am trying to elaborate the concurrent request to get data from Redis for ket **product** with id **1**.

Comment: Can we somehow ask the other requests to wait until the first request has received the data From mysql.